# How to properly set the Python path for the reticulate package in OSX High Sierra?

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I have installed Python 3.7 in the default location for High Sierra using the official OSX package downloaded from the official Python site. When I run

```
which python3
```

I get the path

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

I then run the following lines in R Studio

```
reticulate::use_python(python = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3')
sys <- import("sys")
sys$version
```

It seems that I am still pointing to the default installation of 2.7

```
[1] "2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)]"
```

I tried many other paths such as

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib
/usr/bin/python
/Applications/Python 3.7
```

etc., but none seems to work. (it still shows 2.7.10)

Obviously, I have tried googling for the solution but to no avail unfortunately. 
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Update:**
I finally got it to work by:

1. Restarting the R Session as recommended by serv-inc
2. Running the following commands:

   `library(reticulate)
   reticulate::use_python(python = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3', required = T)
   sys <- import("sys")
   sys$version`

   to get the following response:

   `[1] "3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 26 2018, 23:26:24) \n[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]"`
3. If I have incorrectly specified an incorrect path such as `/usr/bin/python`, I would need to restart the R session or else reticulate would continue referring to the existing Python version.

In short, the problem was caused by the incorrect path specified in the initial call to the `reticulate::use_python` function, and subsequent calls with the correct path would not take effect as it requires a 'fresh' R session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/45:

> Do
>
> ```
> library("reticulate")
> use_python("/usr/bin/python", required = T)
> ```
>
> Before anything else.

See also https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/227:

> reticulate will always prefer a version of Python that includes NumPy to one that doesn't. Does the version at /usr/local/bin/python3 have NumPy?

> Obviously, I have tried googling for the solution

Sometimes, googling only the function name "reticulate::use_python" helps.

Comment: Thanks @serv-inc. Yes, the python3 installation has NumPy installed. Most solutions out there seem to refer to /usr/bin/python but for mac it would be /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 etc, which caused me to second guess my path obtained by `which python3`. Thanks again for your help and pointing me to the document that indicates the need for a clean R session.

Comment: @TheLyrist: you seemed a smart enough fellow to figure out the part with the path. Good that it's working.