# Cannot get `reticulate` working in MacOS arm64 architecture

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I have been trying to use Python in RStudio but apparently, the versions do not match. I have the reticulate version 1.23 installed. I get the following error.

```
> reticulate::repl_python()
Error in py_initialize(config$python, config$libpython, config$pythonhome,  : 
  /Users/harshvardhan/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.8.dylib - dlopen(/Users/harshvardhan/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.8.dylib, 0x000A): tried: '/Users/harshvardhan/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.8.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libpython3.8.dylib' (no such file)
```

However, I have Python installed — I can use it using Anaconda. I can also verify it using `Sys.which("python")`.

```
> Sys.which("python")
           python 
"/usr/bin/python"
```

Another check.

```
> reticulate::conda_list()
          name                                                         python
1  r-miniconda             /Users/harshvardhan/Library/r-miniconda/bin/python
2         base                   /Users/harshvardhan/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
3 r-reticulate /Users/harshvardhan/opt/anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python
```

Whenever I run any Python code from my `.py` script, I get the following error.

```
> reticulate::repl_python()
Error in py_initialize(config$python, config$libpython, config$pythonhome,  : 
  /Users/harshvardhan/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.8.dylib - dlopen(/Users/harshvardhan/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.8.dylib, 0x000A): tried: '/Users/harshvardhan/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.8.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libpython3.8.dylib' (no such file)
> import numpy as np
Error: unexpected symbol in "import numpy"
```

Here's the system information. Any help would be great.

```
> Sys.info()
                                                                                               sysname 
                                                                                              "Darwin" 
                                                                                               release 
                                                                                              "21.2.0" 
                                                                                               version 
"Darwin Kernel Version 21.2.0: Sun Nov 28 20:29:10 PST 2021; root:xnu-8019.61.5~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101" 
                                                                                              nodename 
                                                                     "Harshvardhans-MacBook-Air.local" 
                                                                                               machine 
                                                                                               "arm64" 
                                                                                                 login 
                                                                                                "root" 
                                                                                                  user 
                                                                                        "harshvardhan" 
                                                                                        effective_user 
                                                                                        "harshvardhan"
```

---

Some resources I've tried to no avail. I'd be ecstatic to learn if I missed something.

- https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/1019
- https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/python_packages.html
- https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/1095

Comment: What's the output of `reticulate::py_config()`?

Comment: @PeaceWang
Error : '/usr/bin/python3' was not built with a shared library.
reticulate can only bind to copies of Python built with '--enable-shared'.
Error: Python shared library not found, Python bindings not loaded.
Use reticulate::install_miniconda() if you'd like to install a Miniconda Python environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Here's what worked for me.

First, I opened Terminal and found my Python 3 location.

```
which python
```

gave me

```
/Users/harshvardhan/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Then, I loaded `reticulate`.

```
library(reticulate)
```

Then I ran `use_python()` with `required = T` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52462957/8057777). Then it worked as expected!

```
library("reticulate")
use_python("/usr/bin/python", required = T)
sys = import("sys")
>>> for i in range(10):
...    print(i)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my M1 MAcbook Air. I am also using anaconda but the problem was that the architecture of some dependency (libpython3.9.dylib in my case) was x86_64, I ran `lipo  -info /opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.9.dylib` and the output was

```
Non-fat file: /opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.9.dylib is architecture: x86_64
```

Then I tried creating a native environment on anaconda following the tips from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65415996/how-to-specify-the-architecture-or-platform-for-a-new-conda-environment-apple). I had only two environments (check with `conda env list`) so I ran

```
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-arm64 conda create -n native numpy -c conda-forge
```

then checked that the environment had been created, then

```
conda activate native
conda config --env --set subdir osx-arm64
```

Then I ran again `which python` which gave `/opt/anaconda3/envs/native/bin/python`, and I put this last thing in the reticulate argument:

```
use_python("/opt/anaconda3/envs/native/bin/python", required = TRUE)
```

What was kind of pointless is that now trying to call modules from RSTudio requires me to install all the ones Anaconda already has but I cannot access to (at least not with reticulate).